# TclError: invalid command name ".4318456072"

Tags: python, user-interface, animation, canvas, tkinter

I'm writing a version of snake using tkinter. I've come across an issue when trying to make a canvas widget move for an indefinite amount of time using a `while True` loop. The code appears to work fine but I then get an exception in the console upon closing the window:
Exception in Tkinter callback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1536, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "/Users/rachkids/Documents/Coding/Ball Game.py", line 33, in move_ball_right
    canvas.move(ball, xspeed, yspeed)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 2416, in move
    self.tk.call((self._w, 'move') + args)
TclError: invalid command name ".4318456072"
```

Here is the function to make the object move:

```
def move_ball_right(event):
    global spaceright
    global spaceleft
    if spaceright != 400:
        while True:
            xspeed = 10
            yspeed = 0
            canvas.move(ball, xspeed, yspeed)
            Tk.update(window1)
            spaceright = spaceright + 10
            spaceleft = spaceleft + 10
            time.sleep(0.25)
```

Here is all of my code so far:

```
from Tkinter import *
from Tkinter import Canvas
import random
import time

window1 = Tk()
window1.title("Ball Game")
window1.config(background="black")
window1.geometry("400x400")
coord1 = 0
coord2 = 0
coord3 = 20
coord4 = 20
spaceright = 20
spaceleft = 400
spaceup = 400
spacedown = 20
random1 = random.choice([20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100,110,120,130,140,150,160,170,180,190,200,210,220,230,240,250,260,270,280,290,300,310,320,330,340,350,360,370,380])
random2 = random1 + 20


def generate_food():
    food = canvas.create_rectangle(random1, random1, random2, random2, fill="red")


def move_ball_right(event):
    global spaceright
    global spaceleft
    if spaceright != 400:
        while True:
            xspeed = 10
            yspeed = 0
            canvas.move(ball, xspeed, yspeed)
            Tk.update(window1)
            spaceright = spaceright + 10
            spaceleft = spaceleft + 10
            time.sleep(0.25)


def move_ball_left (event):
    global spaceright
    global spaceleft
    if spaceleft != 400:
        xspeed = -10
        yspeed = 0
        canvas.move(ball, xspeed, yspeed)
        Tk.update(window1)
        spaceleft = spaceleft - 10
        spaceright = spaceright - 10


def move_ball_down (event):
    global spacedown
    global spaceup
    if spacedown != 400:
        xspeed = 0
        yspeed = 10
        canvas.move(ball, xspeed, yspeed)
        Tk.update(window1)
        spacedown = spacedown + 10
        spaceup = spaceup + 10


def move_ball_up (event):
    global spacedown
    global spaceup
    if spaceup != 400:
        xspeed = 0
        yspeed = -10
        canvas.move(ball, xspeed, yspeed)
        Tk.update(window1)
        spaceup = spaceup - 10
        spacedown = spacedown - 10


canvas = Canvas(window1, width=400, height=400, bg="black", bd=0, highlightthickness=0, relief="ridge")
canvas.pack()
generate_food()
ball = canvas.create_rectangle(coord1, coord2, coord3, coord4, fill="white")
window1.bind('<Right>', move_ball_right)
window1.bind('<Left>', move_ball_left)
window1.bind('<Down>', move_ball_down)
window1.bind('<Up>', move_ball_up)
window1.mainloop()
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because when you kill the tkinter window, the canvas object is also destroyed, being a child of the tkinter window (in this instance the canvas is reported as an object number .4318456072). But the while loop is still running -- even though the tkinter window is gone. But the canvas object doesn't exist, which generates the error.

Correcting can include putting a try/expect block around the canvas.move statement and cause the while loop to break when this exception occurs.

In particular, anything to do with tkinter within the while loop should be caught. Very trivial error checking here could be:

```
try:
    canvas.move(ball, xspeed, yspeed)
    Tk.update(window1)
except:
    break
```